# How to use gcc instead of clang

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, build, clang

I am trying to build an android version from Github and I would like to compile it with gcc, the instructions say to input "make efi_img -jN" but i always get a clang error. I am very new with Unix so i would appreciate any help using gcc instead of clang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find out the name of the compiler variable in the Makefile. If it's a C project it's probably `CC`. If it's a C++ project it's probably `CXX`.

Then invoke `make` by assigning the name of the GCC executable to that variable:

```
make CXX=g++ efi_img -jN
```